# Laravel 5.1 How to pass the id of an object to another view to be used as the foreign key in another table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a projects table and a quotes table with the following structure:

```
Schema::create('quotes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('project_id')->index()->unsigned();
            $table->decimal('quote', 10,0);
            $table->timestamps();
```

On the project page I need a link which refers to the page for creating a new quote. How can I pass the id of a project to the create view of a quote?

**UPDATE**

I tried flashing the project id to the session an then getting it in the quote controller but by the time I'm trying to get it there the session is emty!

```
//flashing project_id to the session
        $request->session()->flash('project_id', $project->id);
or
        $request->session()->flash('project_id', $project->id);
        $request->session()->reflash();
or
        $request->session()->flash('project_id', $project->id);
        $request->session()->keep(['project_id']);;
//getting it in quote controller
        $project_id=$request->session()->get('project_id');
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which worked.In the show method of projects controller I used the `put()` method to flash the project->id to the session:

```
$request->session()->put('project_id', $project->id);
```

then in the create method of quotes controller I used the `pull()` method to get the project_id out of session.

```
$id=$request->session()->pull('project_id');
```

But there was a little problem with this approach, and in case the user decides to refresh the form page there will be no project_id key in session. To tackle this I decided to redirect the user to the list of projects to select one again.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that U have a Project model and `$project` is an instance of it. Get Id of the project and pass it to the quote view like this:

```
$project_id = $project->id;
return redirect()->intended('your_view')->with('project_id' , $project_id);
```

the `$project_id` is stored in the sessions. So you can easily retrieve it like this in the blade:

```
if(session()->has('project_id')){
    $project_id = session('project_id');
    // do whatever u want with the $project_id and set it in quote table
}
```

Comment: @peyman-h Thank you but the link to the create quote view is in on a show project view and I already have access to $project->id. The problem is how to pass this variable to the next view, that is the create quote view to be used in the quote controller

Answer (score 1):

First, you can define resourceful routes like this:

```
Route::resource('projects.quotes', 'QuotesController');
```

Now, in your project page place this code where you want to display the link to create quotes:

```
{!! link_to_route('projects.quotes.create', 'Create Quote', $project->id) !!}
```

Now, modify your QuotesController's create function like this:

```
public function create($project_id)
{
    $project = App\Project::find($project_id);
    return view('quotes.create', compact('project'));
}
```

Now, you can use $project data in your create.php or create.blade.php view file

Comment: Thanks, but this method is not working. It will create a link like this: quote/create?1 which I cannot use in the quote controller.

Comment: Why you cannot use it in quotes controller?

Comment: because no such route is defined

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allows you to share variables between views. You can add it to the existing  `AppServiceProvider` or create your own.

In the selected service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->share('username','Joe');
}
```

The variable `$username` is available to all views. 
You can also call `share` method from the controller or anywhere before you render the view.

```
View::share('key','value');
```

Hope this help

Comment: I think this approach is most appropriate for variables like 'username' which is fixed in a session.